# Can I make all section headings bigger?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, sectsty

I want to make all section headings in LaTeX document bigger by a given scale. For example, I want all of them have 150% of size that they have now.

Can I do that somehow? (Ideally using `sectsty`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution with `sectsty` should be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\larger[2]} 

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
\subsection{Subsection title}
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't recommend it. The size of section titles in the standard classes is already quite large.

Comment: OK, the error was my mistake. It seems like it worked, thanks!

Comment: Even though I've posted my own solution, this one is obviously better.

Comment: @tohecz: I actually have some more changes to the font, using `\sectsty`, which is making it appear too small, that's why I asked for `\sectsty` specifically. Thanks for your answer though

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the package `sectsty`, but the following dirty trick using `titlesec` should work. Just add these lines into your preamble (and do not use `sectsty` at the same time...):

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{relsize}
\titlelabel{\larger\larger\thetitle\quad\aftergroup\larger\aftergroup\larger}
```

The trick is that `\larger` multiplies the current font size by `1.2` (in most cases). Applied twice it makes `1.44`, which is very close to `1.5`. The command `\titlelabel` change the way how the section numbers are printed. The sequence `\aftergroup\larger` makes sure that the magnification is applied to the section title as well.

Comment: [cz] Mimochodem, zdravím :)

Comment: Is there any way to apply this to just the section titles, not the subsection titles?

Comment: @supercoolphysicist If you want it only for one title type, you should really modify this one title type in the standard way the package offers. Just read its documentation.