# How to change section/subsection font size?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, titlesec

I'm writing a paper that requires the section titles to be in `12pt` font, I can get the title to be in `12pt` using:

```
\section{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont Introduction}
```

but the section number does not change size, is there a way to do this?

I've also tried looking at `titlesec` but have not been able to find any suitable examples.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should look up the `titlesec` package, which makes it easy to customise the formatting of section-unit titles.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764); [Can I make all section headings bigger?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67336/5764); [How to set the font for a `\section` title (and chapter etc)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1455/5764); [Change section fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10138/5764)

Comment: @Werner I think that no duplicates here. None of these say what to do, if you want exact "N pt" size, while writing some papers sometimes have such editorial requirements. And this is what Op is asking for =) [I have the same problem =( ]

Comment: @Kusavil: The selected answer covers this using `\fontsize`. The duplicates cover a general case, where you can use standard font switches.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
test

\end{document}
```

The [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package could also be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful to see how to set the font size to a specified pt size.

Comment: Note, if you do the same thing (with the `titlesec` package) for a subsection, then replace `\thesection` with `\thesubsection`.

Comment: The `titlesec` solution seems to work for sections and subsections, but not for parts and chapters in the `book` class. And my editor wants 13pt for the part title. Is there a solution for this with `titlesec`?

Comment: Would it be possilbe to edit this answer to clarify what the arguments `{12}{15}` mean for the `\fontsize` command? Why are there two sizes? What do each mean? Under what scenarios would changing the first/second number be expected to change the actual font size?

Comment: @Mrule 12 is the text size and 15 the title font size

Comment: Smauel Saari, that is not right.  @MRule, the sintax is `\fontsize{<size>}{<line space>}`. See [LatexFonts at wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts).