# Correct font size of section and subsection

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[noragright,centerchapter,12pt]{thesis}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\author{cat}
\title{cat}
\adviser{cat}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\parindent 1em%

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{cats}
\section{cats}
\subsection{cats}

\end{document}

"thesis.cls" is a style file provided by my university.
```

Can some please help me as to how I can make the font size of the subsections the same as that of section? My thesis needs to have the same font throughout...many thanks again

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103286/how-to-change-section-subsection-font-size/103290#103290 (and/or it's related question).  This will be hard to answer definitively without the actual `thesis.cls` file.

Comment: If it's provided by the university, what's your reason for changing it? When you say "needs to have the same font throughout" that sounds like a requirement placed on you by the university - but if they provide the template, that's their problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\LARGE\bfseries}
```

to set both the sizes to `\LARGE`.  Adjust as needed.