# Chapters and sections without oldstyle numbers

Tags: oldstylenums

I want to use `\usepackage[sfdefault]{merriweather}`, but without the oldstyle numbers. So, I wanted to change the font for numbers on the sections and chapters or use a similar font (Helvetica, maybe?).

I think that the [`sectsty` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) has a solution: `\partnumberfont` and `\chapternumberfont`.

Unfortunately, I can not use this package. Also, I cannot use XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Update.:
@runartrollet give the solution:

```
\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\selectfont
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

Now I have a correlated question, I don't know if I need to create another topic: There is some way to change all "merriweather" numbers to helvetica numbers?

Comment: Nowhere. It works with just the plain installation on Mac OS.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @CostaPR If you want to substitute every numeral in the font with the numerals from a different font, I think you would have to do something very complicated. kerning could be a problem. You could try to make a new question, and maybe some of the super wizards around here could give you a great answer, but I suspect they will just tell you that it shouldn't be done.

Comment: @CostaPR I found another post which gives an answer on how to replace a symbol with another symbol from another font. It seeks to replace just a single letter, a german one, but you could use the same code to replace all the numbers. Have a look at [Importing “ß” from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312349/89976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this font includes table-numerals(or uppercase-numerals), so you will have to replace the font for the numbers. I would advice against this, as old style numerals do bring a sense of style in. If you want to do it for only the chapter/section-titles, I would change the font for the whole title, not just the number.

> Please do not mix fonts like this on the same line, it is really ugly! It is better to change the font for the whole section/chapter -title, have a look at [Gonzalo Medina's answer to How to change section/subsection font size? [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103290/89976) for details on how to change section-style.

Below, I have changed only the font for the number, but I haven't really spent any time finding a font that actaully fits, so it looks quite ugly. You might bea ble to find one that is more fitting. Again, I would adice against this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{merriweather}
\usefont{T1}{fxl}{m}{n}\selectfont
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{\selectfont \arabic{section}}} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\selectfont \arabic{chapter}}} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks quite ugly indeed.

Comment: yep, you really shouldn't do this

Comment: I will search for another font... I hate these old style numbers on the chapter number...

Comment: @CostaPR I added a note with a link on how to change the font for the whole section/chapter, which I believe would make it look a lot better than only changing the font for the counter.