# Any easy way to change the section font size in a LaTex article?

Tags: fontsize

The default section head font size is 17, and subsection is 14. Any simple way to change them to, say 16 and 13? Just the size, nothing else.

I've googled for solutions and those I find are either too complicated or do not work.

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103286/how-to-change-section-subsection-font-size).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lines in your preamble should do the trick:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{16}{20}\selectfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{13}{17}\selectfont}
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the second numbers mean, 20 and 17?

Comment: The interline spacing. It should about 20-25 % more than the font size ( for a standard 10 pt document, you can measure it is equal to 12 pt).

Comment: @Bernard Can you please tell me how to apply bold effect with the above solution?

Comment: @AtanuCSE: normally, this should be automatic if you use one of the standard classes. If you don't use one  of them, could you  please post a small but complete example code?