# Changing section heading font size without titlesec nor sectsty

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, japanese

Many questions (e.g. [59726](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti)
[67336](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/can-i-make-all-section-headings-bigger) [1455](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc) [59726](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti)) address the issue of how to change font attributes in section (and subsections etc). All of the ones I've seen end up requiring packages such as `titlesec` or `sectsty`, or suggest changing the document class to KOMA or something.

**QUESTION**: how to change the font attributes *WITHOUT* inserting additional packages nor changing the document class?

I ask this since I am using a specific document class called [jlreq](https://github.com/abenori/jlreq) (a very good class for Japanese documents, specially if you need vertical writing) which conflicts with both packages abovementioned.

Comment: You can use another package, `xpatch`  (non specialised in sections formatting) ;which enables to patch commands in any package or document class, in particular to replace the default font sizes with the ones you want.

Comment: I think your question is very specific to the `jlreq` document class, and a generic answer will not likely work. If you look at lines 5909 and following of the class, that's where the heading specifications are made using the class macro `\NewBlockHeading`. One of the keys supplied to the third argument of that macro is `font={...}` with the font specification. Since the documentation is only in Japanese, I'm afraid I can't help you further.

Comment: @AlanMunn thank you very much! I looked up on the file and changed the specifications. Sorry for taking so long to answer. Thanks again!